# Что такое IIFE и как это работает

Tags: javascript

Последняя задача отсюда: https://learn.javascript.ru/closures-usage. 
Комментарии автора к решению совершенно меня запутали.
Может кто-нибудь здесь поможет разложить в моей голове все по полочкам?

```js
function makeArmy() {

  var shooters = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var shooter = function(x) {

      return function() {
        console.log( x );
      };

    }(i);

    shooters.push(shooter);
  }

  return shooters;
}

var army = makeArmy();

army[0]();
army[5]();
```

Непонятен конкретно этот момент:

```
  var shooter = function(x) {

    return function() {
      console.log( x );
    };

  }(i);
```

Какую функцию вызывает вот это `(i)` и откуда  `x` передается аргументом ?

Comment: Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, дать вопросу нормальное название

Comment: @Kromster Я сильно старался, но ничего не придумал

Comment: то что вас запутало называется `IIFE`

Comment: Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, еще немного сильнее. В текущем виде это желтизна и привлекает поставить ей минус.

Comment: Я попробовал поменять название)) Звучит не так броско, но суть вопроса, вроде как отражает ( да и для поиска очень хорошее название )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var shooter = function(x) {

    return function() {
      console.log( x );
    };

  }(i);
```

Код, который вас смутил, это [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/IIFE). 
По русски - *Немедленно выполняемое функциональное выражение*

Можно еще встретить такой вариант ( разницы нет ):

```
  var shooter = (function(x) {

    return function() {
      console.log( x );
    };

  })(i);
```

Работает это так: в переменную `shooter` запишется не сама функция, а ее результат, потому что мы после определения функции ее сразу же вызываем. Пример ваш можно переписать вот так

```
  function foo(x) {

    return function() {
      console.log( x );
    };

  }
  const i = 10;
  const shooter = foo(i);
```

Но, в примере с IIFE мы не загрязняем область видимости всякими `foo`, просто берем функцию, выполняем ее и забываем. Это полезно для создания замыканий, как например, в данном случае.

> и откуда  x передается аргументом

`x` аргумент берется как раз из последующего вызова `(i)`

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что смутило автора IIFE, а не сам возврат функции в принципе? может ему вообще конструкция `return function()` не понятна.

Comment: @teran последующие вопрос про аргумент на это намекает

Comment: @teran ну и что ответ приняли:D

Comment: @ThisMan Спасибо вам огромное, после примера с foo стало все понятно.

Comment: @ThisMan  а да, пока комменты читал, забыл чем вопрос закончился :D